# 'REACT_APP_VERSION' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm, nodes

I am trying to run a react project in my Windows environment but It's throwing the following error. Before, this project worked on Ubuntu with the same things. It started to happen after I changed the OS. How can I fix this?

I am just running **npm start** command.

```
> REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version react-scripts -r @cypress/instrument-cra start

'REACT_APP_VERSION' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! PROJECT NAME start: `REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version react-scripts -r @cypress/instrument-cra start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the PROJECT NAME start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

**UPDATE**
I just fixed it with the following package. It is about windows.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Thanks.